# Bootstrap requires jQuery

Tags: jquery

It's very weird but true. I am getting this error all the time from safari and chrome. bootstrap requires jQuery. 
this is how I embed my js files

```
</footer>
</body>
<script async src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script async src="js/js.js"></script>
</html>
```

and this is how it looks like in Safari
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etcOO.png) 
and this is how it looks like in Chrome
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moTlM.png)

Comment: Do you have `jquery.js` file in your `js` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `async` attributes. Bootstrap code should load after jQuery, which is currently not the case.

Comment: thank you very much. now it works fine in safari and chrome.